# Create current date in String format and parse to date as string in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

**Goal:**

1. I need to first create a String representing the current date.
2. Afterwards this String needs to be parsed and used to build an instance of the Date class.

**Initial attempt:**

In my test class I create a current date as a String input for my tested method in the following manner:

```
String inputDate = date.today().format(); // 13:28:15:378 USER_DEBUG [24]|DEBUG|17.3.2017
```

However, when I attempt to create an instance of a Date object like this:

```
Date dateFromInput = date.valueOf(inputDate);
```

I receive the following error:

```
13:28:15:398 FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Invalid date: 17.3.2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.format()` will return string in current local date format of logged in user.

`Date.valueOf` needs input string in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in the local time zone.

Below should work:

```
String inputDate = date.today().format('**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**');
Date dateFromInput = date.parse(inputDate);
```

Comment: Old but this is worth mention for anyone else that comes across this.


That first line is not valid Apex, Date does not support a String pattern in the format() function:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm


Running that code from the Anonymous Execution window of the developer console will yield this message:
Line: 1, Column: 33
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void format(String) from the type Date


DateTime on the other does handle string formats nicely.

Comment: system.debug(Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd')); // tested in anonymous window and it works.

Comment: Right `DateTime format('yyyy-MM-dd')` works but `Date format('yyyy-MM-dd')` does not.  `Date format()` however does work.

Answer (score 3):

Following code

```
((DateTime)Dob).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
```

Just Works

Answer (score 0):

[In the documentation, there is a difference between the parse and valueOf Date methods that escaped me:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

**parse(stringDate)**
*Constructs a Date from a String. The format of the String depends on the local date format.*

**valueOf(stringDate)**
*Returns a Date that contains the value of the specified String.*

What I wanted was the parse:

```
String inputDate = date.today().format(); /
Date dateFromInput = date.parse(inputDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Moment.apex`. Here is the [link](https://github.com/Click-to-Cloud/Moment.apex)

```
Datetime dt = new Moment('2018/01/12 10:00:00', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').toDatetime();
```

Comment: Does moment.apex support parsing custom date formats i.e. C# Date.ParseExact?

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? I don't see one in the repository.

Comment: Constructing the Moment instance using datetime string and format string is actually a process of parsing the datetime using the custom date format.